# Conversion de Char a int: trato de convertir letras a números (números romanos)

Tags: java

Trato de convertir letras a números(números romanos) al llamar la función me da error.
Tengo esta función:

```
public static int ConversionLetraNumero(char letra){
    int num;
    
    switch(letra){
        case 'I' : num = 1; break;
        case 'V' : num = 5; break;
        case 'X' : num = 10; break;
        case 'L' : num = 50; break;
        case 'C' : num = 100; break;
        case 'D' : num = 500; break;
        case 'M' : num = 1000; break;
        default: num=0;
}
    return num;
}
```

La clase donde tengo el error es está:

```
public class FD_20130777_Frame_02 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ConversionLetraNumero operar = new ConversionLetraNumero();

public FD_20130777_Frame_02() {
    initComponents();
}

public static int ConversionLetraNumero(char letra){
    int num;
    
    switch(letra){
        case 'I' : num = 1; break;
        case 'V' : num = 5; break;
        case 'X' : num = 10; break;
        case 'L' : num = 50; break;
        case 'C' : num = 100; break;
        case 'D' : num = 500; break;
        case 'M' : num = 1000; break;
        default: num=0;
}
    return num;
}

// al tratar de llamar a la funcion me da error 
private void btnRestarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String num1 = txtNum1.getText();
    operar.ConversionLetraNumero(num1);
}
```

Al tratar de llamar a la función me da error.

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida para que conozcas qué es un [mcve] y por qué es importante aportar todos los datos que ayuden a entender tu escenario

Comment: Deberias asegurarte de que le pasas un char a la función. Lo más probable es que le estes pasando un String